# "Conforms" or "Complies" as a table record in an official quality check document

Tags: synonyms, comparison, formal-language

From an [example Quality Overall Summary (QOS) document by FDA](http://www.fda.gov/downloads/Drugs/DevelopmentApprovalProcess/HowDrugsareDevelopedandApproved/ApprovalApplications/AbbreviatedNewDrugApplicationANDAGenerics/ucm120977.pdf):

[image]

Can we use "conforms" in such cases (in the final column), or is "complies" the only option? What are acceptable synonyms for use in such table cells?

I know the meaning of the two words, and it does overlap:

> The substance **conforms to** the requirements.
>   The substance **complies with** the requirements.

Here both options seem okay. I'd like to know if "conforms" is okay in a formal document like the one quoted above.

---

> Dear is that shed to which his soul conforms,
>   And dear that hill which lifts him to the storms.

Here "complies" would look strange. "Complies" is a more active verb, it seems. You can comply with rules, but not with a shed.

> Dear is that shed with which his soul complies,
>   And dear that hill which lifts him to the skies.

^_^

Comment: Did you check the definitions of "conform" and "comply"? These should be part of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either may be used in a formal document, and they have effectively the same meaning in this context. Compare their two definitions (from Oxford Dictionaries):

> [**comply**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/comply)
>   [NO OBJECT] (often **comply with**)
>   (Of an article) meet specified standards:
>   "*all second-hand furniture must comply with the new regulations*"
>
> [**conform**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/conform)
>   [NO OBJECT]
>   Comply with rules, standards, or laws:
>   "*the kitchen does not conform to hygiene regulations*"
>   "*the changes were introduced to conform with international classifications*"

As you can see, the definition for *conform* uses the word *comply*.

One instance where they are not interchangeable, especially in the context of the FDA or another regulatory body, is if an order is issued to a company. In that case, the company must *comply* with the order.

*Compliance* is always with a standard, wish, command, or order. *Conformance* (also *conformity*) is broader: you can *conform to* standards, an idea or preconception, or to the shape of a something (liquids conform to the shape of their container), among other things.

Other words you may be interested in, especially in a regulatory or legal context, are [*accordance*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/accordance) and [*pursuance*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pursuance). Food may be prepared *in accordance with*, in a manner [*accordant to*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/accordant), or [*pursuant to*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pursuant) hygiene regulation.